# Get only a submodule from a git repo

Tags: git, git-submodules

I would like to know if there's a way to only get access to a submodule directory from a git repo, without cloning the git repo fully or even using `git init`, if possible. I only need the submodules.

For example;

I only want to get the submodules from this git repo `git://git.linphone.org/linphone-android.git`, which contains a set of codecs.

If anyone can help me with this question, i would be grateful, thank you.

Comment: Submodules essentially just point at some other git repo, you can see the [list of them here](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android/blob/master/.gitmodules). Given this file, you could just write a small bash script that clones each of those as its own repo if you want.

Comment: Note that you can't do it with raw Git (you have to clone the main repo just to find the `.gitmodules` file!) but you can easily do it with most hosted systems, which let you read the `.gitmodules` file from the hosted repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, yes.

As CoryKramer points out in the comments on your question, you can get a list of currently active submodules from [the .gitmodules file](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android/blob/master/.gitmodules).

Since you grab that file straight from github (using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android/master/.gitmodules), you can easily feed that into a script that will checkout the individidual modules:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android/master/.gitmodules |
awk '$1 == "url" {print $3}' |
xargs -n1 git clone
```

You won't be able to determine the specific *commit* used in each submodule without cloning the parent repository, but if all you need is the HEAD for each project you should be all set.

This solution is obviously only valid for repositories that are hosted in such a fashion that you can access individual files without cloning the entire repository.  So, it works great for github hosted repositories, but it's not a general "git" solution.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, no.

When you get a git repository, you get it all.
The reason is git don't see individual file or folder, it sees the whole context.

But you have a choice to put the "modules" as standalone git repositories. Then you can just clone the repository for that specific module. And manage these sub modules with `git submodule`.

Many years ago, when Mr. Linus giving talk about Git at Google, he answered this question, start from 43 minute 11 seconds in this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XpnKHJAok8

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git sub-module update --remote` or `git sub-module update --remote --merge` to merge all sub-modules.

The Foreach command will preform a task on each sub-module `git submodule foreach 'git stash'`

Both of these will update all sub-modules. I think the best way to update only one module would to be remove it an re-add that specific module

`$ git rm -r YourLibrary
$ git submodule add https://github.com/username/YourLibrary`

> https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Is this a typo in `git sub-module`? I assume this should be `git submodule`.